# SAS removing duplicates by the reappearance of chunks of records

Tags: sas, datastep

I have a dataset with the reappearance of chunks of data in identical length groups of observations, such as:

```
    data have;
    input name $    identifier ;
    cards;
    mary     1
    mary     2
    mary     2
    mary     4
    mary     5
    mary     7
    mary     6
    adam     2
    adam     3
    adam     3
    adam     7
    /*remove*/
    mary     1
    mary     2
    mary     2
    mary     4
    mary     5
    mary     7
    mary     6
    /*remove*/
    adam     8
    mary     1
    mary     2
    mary     3
    mary     4
    mary     5
    mary     7
    mary     6
    adam    9
    mary     1
    mary     2
    mary     3

    ;
```

I'm hoping to remove the chunk of reappearance of mary marked by /*remove*/ with ordered identifier. The outcome should be like the following:

```
mary     1
mary     2
mary     4
mary     5
mary     6
mary     7
adam    2 
adam    3 
adam    7
adam    8
mary     1
mary     2
mary     3
mary     4
mary     5
mary     6
mary     7
adam     9
mary     1
mary     2
mary     3
```

Thank you for any help! Someone suggested a method by Hash table, but I suspect that I may not have enough memory to process the code. Could this be done by datasteps or proc sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the maximum number of records per group is small enough then here is method you could use that builds a string with the list of identifiers in the group and uses it as one of the keys in the HASH.

```
data want ;
do until (last.name);
  set have ;
  by name notsorted ;
  length taglist $200 ;
  taglist=catx('|',taglist,identifier);
end;
if _n_=1 then do;
  dcl hash h();
  h.defineKey('name','taglist');
  h.defineDone();
end;
found = 0 ne h.add();
do until (last.name);
  set have ;
  by name notsorted ;
  if not found then output;
end;
drop found taglist;
run;
```

If the keys are too large to fit into a hash object then you will need to do multiple pass. First find the groups. Then find the first occurrence of each type of group. Then generate the data for those groups.

```
data pass1 ;
  group + 1;
  first_obs=row+1;
  do until (last.name);
    set have ;
    by name notsorted ;
    length taglist $200 ;
    taglist=catx('|',taglist,identifier);
    row+1;
  end;
  last_obs=row;
  output;
  keep group name taglist first_obs last_obs;
run;

proc sql ;
  create table pass2 as
    select group,first_obs,last_obs
    from pass1
    group by name,taglist
    having min(group)=group
    order by group
  ;
quit;

data want;
  set pass2;
  do obs=first_obs to last_obs;
    set have point=obs;
    output;
  end;
  drop /*group*/ first_obs last_obs ;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs    group    name    identifier

  1      1      mary         1
  2      1      mary         2
  3      1      mary         2
  4      1      mary         4
  5      1      mary         5
  6      1      mary         7
  7      1      mary         6
  8      2      adam         2
  9      2      adam         3
 10      2      adam         3
 11      2      adam         7
 12      4      adam         8
 13      5      mary         1
 14      5      mary         2
 15      5      mary         3
 16      5      mary         4
 17      5      mary         5
 18      5      mary         7
 19      5      mary         6
 20      6      adam         9
 21      7      mary         1
 22      7      mary         2
 23      7      mary         3
```

Comment: The dataset size is about 800million bytes. There is usually not enough memory for hash.

Comment: Is the dataset only those two variables?  You could possibly do it without hash, but the real question is: Can the variable TAGLIST actually be created? What is the maximum length of any "group"?   Will the list of identifiers fit into a single character variable? SAS has a limit of 32K bytes per character variable.

Comment: I do not know the max length of the group since the data will be imported daily, and analysis will be done by real-time. The length will be very long up to 300+items because it is online user log data. The identifier will have varying lengths since some of them will be timestamps. It sounds horrible, but that is the reality I'm dealing with.